# Match movie filenames with optional parts with regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-group

I have a film title in the following format

```
(Studio Name) - Film Title Part-1** - Animation** (2014).mp4
```

The part in BOLD is optional, meaning I can have a title such as this

```
(Studio Name) - Film Title Part-1 (2014).mp4
```

With this regex

```
^\((?P<studio>.+)\) - (?P<title>.+)(?P<genre>-.+)\((?P<year>\d{4})\)
```

I get the following results

```
studio = Studio Name
title  = Film Title Part-1
genre  = - Animation
year   = 2014
```

I have tried the following to make the ***"- Animation"*** optional by changing the regex to

```
^\((?P<studio>.+)\) - (?P<title>.+)(?:(?P<genre>-.+)?)\((?P<year>\d{4})\)
```

but I end up with the following results

```
studio = Studio Name
title  = Film Title Part-1 - Animation
genre  = 
year   = 2014
```

I am using Python, the code that I am executing to process the regex is

```
pattern = re.compile(REGEX) 
matched = pattern.search(film)
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\((?P<studio>[^()]+)\) - (?P<title>.+?)(?P<genre>- \w+ )?\((?P<year>\d{4})\)` https://regex101.com/r/odRLPC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the non capturing group around the genre, make change the first `.*` to a negated character class `[^()]` matching any char except parenthesis and make the `.+` in greoup title non greedy to allow matching the optional genre group.

For the genre, you could match `.+`, or make the match more specific if you only want to match a single word.

```
^\((?P<studio>[^()]+)\) - (?P<title>.+?)(?P<genre>- \w+ )?\((?P<year>\d{4})\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/odRLPC/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\((?P<studio>[^()]+)\)` Named group studio match any char except parenthesis between `(` and `)`
- `-`  Match literally
- `(?P<title>.+?)` Named group *title*, match any char except a newline as least as possible
- `(?P<genre>- \w+ )?` Named group *genre*, match `-` space, 1+ word chars and space
- `\((?P<year>\d{4})\)` named group *year*, match 4 digits between `(` and `)`

If you want to match the whole line:

```
^\((?P<studio>[^()]+)\) - (?P<title>.+?)(?P<genre>- \w+ )?\((?P<year>\d{4})\)\.mp4$
```

Comment: that worked brilliantly but did exactly what my initial code ```^\((?P<studio>.+)\) - (?P<title>.+)(?P<genre>-.+)\((?P<year>\d{4})\)``` but I like the w+ - .

Comment: I still don't fully understand this part ```^\((?P<studio>[^()]+)\) ``` if one can match everything with the brackets - is it possible to write a regex that simply picks everything between 2 brackets including the brackets thmeselves... thus avoiding having to escape the enclosing brackets?

Comment: This part `[^()]+` matches any char except the `(` and the `)` to prevent backtracking. If you also want to match parenthesis, you could make it non greedy instead. `^\((?P<studio>.*?)\) - (?P<title>.+?)(?P<genre>- \w+ )?\((?P<year>\d{4})\)`  See https://regex101.com/r/IJyUTQ/1